# Practical way to interprete elements of extension fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, finite-fields

If I consider $\newcommand\F{\mathbb F}\F_{p^{16}}\cong\F_p[x]/(x^{16}-2)$. Assume that this is a valid field extension.

How to get an $A\in\F_{p^{16}}$ in isomorphic representation? Is there a nice way to choose the coefficients $A=\sum_{i=0}^{15}a_ix^i$?

Comment: What is $A$? How was it given to you? Whatever your answer to those questions, there is likely a simple answer to your question: it's a linear algebra problem over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Probably a change of basis problem. So you can just do linear algebra.

Comment: Isn't it cost-expensive? Assume A is given as an Element of $\mathbb N$. There are a lot of equations to be solved.

Comment: A 16-dimensional linear algebra problem is trivial work for computers to do. "How is $A$ given to you" requires you to explain the actual data format, not just the data. In particular, I assume you don't mean the standard mapping from integers to $\mathbb{F}_{p^{16}}$, which is simply the element of $\mathbb{F}_p$ given by reduction mod p.

Comment: If you gave us the origin of $A$ it might be able to make an educated guess. But (peeking at your other questions), if we have for example $A=-2^{7k+6}$, then you really only reduce $A$ modulo $p$ to get $a_0$ and $a_i=0$ for all $i>0$. I somehow have the impression that you know this. That's  why I join in Hurkyl's query about the data format. My experience with ultra large finite fields is somewhat limited, but I'm not aware of other integer formats for finite fields of characteristic $p>2$. In characteristic two you often see formatting coming from equating $x$ with $2=0b00000010$.

Comment: A could be given in two ways: The easy one "$A=(a_0, a_1, ..., a_{15})$" with entries from $\mathbb F_p$ or as a hard one: "A=0x...." as a hexadecimal string. The easy one is allready a polynomial and can, therefore, be handled like this. But the hard one is... hard I would say. ;)

Comment: Without telling us what the **format** of that hexadecimal string is, it is surely impossible to say anything about how to do the conversion. Is it a discrete logarithm w.r.t. some primitive element? Are the sixteen coefficients $a_i$ just concatenated there? There is no "standard" At least not one I would be aware of. Check your source! May be copy the definition of that format here?

Comment: @Shalec: You still haven't explained the format of the "easy one". I would usually guess you mean the coefficients of a polynomial in some generator (and wonder why you didn't just write that polynomial), but *what* generator? Given the context I would usually guess the generator $x$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^{16}-2)$, but then your question of how to get the representation of $A$ doesn't seem to make sense because then it would already be given to you in the form you're asking for!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I didn't know, that there is no standard. It is a large random integer presented to the base 16. It coult be stored as a character of ~50 words. The easy format is just a polynomial $$A=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{15} a_ix^i =:(a_0,...,a_{15})$$ an those coefficients are stored. In the easy method my question is allready solved. The hard one is still to solve. But this seems to be only linear algebra and solving some equation systems.

Comment: For all I know there may well be "a standard". But, IMHO, whoever uses such a field should surely explain there notation. Particularly if they expect others to use their system. Standard or not.